# JavaScript: how to rename all keys in an object (process all keys on the first level)?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a prefix to the first level of keys in an object.

To leave less ambiguity, I hope that it's OK to show how a dictionary comprehension in Python is an elegant way for achieving this (and I am looking for an analogous approach in JavaScript):

```py
>>> old = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
>>> prefix = "_"
>>> new = {prefix + key: value for key, value in old.items()}
>>> new
{'_a': 1, '_b': 2}
```

What's  a similarly elegant and especially readable way for doing this in modern JavaScript, ideally available in NodeJS 12?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the object to entries via [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Iterate the entries with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and update the key. Convert the entries to object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const old = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
const prefix = "_"

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(old).map(([k, v]) => [`${prefix}${k}`, v])
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Also just found fromEntries, deleting my answer again. You were faster. :)

Comment: Adding this here: `Object.fromEntries` is quite new, it's in the initial definition in ECMAScript 2019. But it's indeed already available in Node 12. Thank you!

Comment: Another note, in Typescript's `tsconfig.json` this requires `"target": "es2019"` so that it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var json = {'k': 'v', 'm': 'n'};
var prefix = '_';

var val = Object.assign(
  {},
  ...Object.keys(json).map(key => ({[prefix+key]: json[key]}))
)

console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a combination of Object.entries and reduce; I think this will have fewer iterations through the object that other solutions.

```js
const obj = {"a": 1, "b": 2};

const newObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[`_${key}`] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newObj);
```